# Why is the Convert.ToBase64String method not outputting the correct value

Tags: c#, base64

I am trying to convert a byte[] to a Base64 string.

```
string output = Convert.ToBase64String(SQLDataHelper.EncryptAddValue(modifiedField.Value[nameof(RecordHistoryField.PreviousValue)]));
```

After plugging this output value into an online Base64 to Binary converter, I can see that it is not the correct value. It returns a list of random characters.

Note that the byte[] is showing the correct values ex: {94, 85, 60, ...} and when I convert it to a hex string, it gives me the binary that I am expecting, just with no 0x.

Edit:

Input: `{94, 85, 60, 64, 62, 69, 77, 65, 131, 20, 125, 110, 136, 128, 87, 112}`

Expected output: `MHg1RTU1M0M0MDNFNDU0RDQxODMxNDdENkU4ODgwNTc3MA==`

Actual output: `XlU8QD5FTUGDFH1uiIBXcA==`

Comment: So, what is the byte array, what would be the expected outcome, and what is the actual outcome?

Comment: Edit the question to add a sample input along with expected and actual outputs.

Comment: Giving the input as a string would be better.

Answer (score 2):

The expected result is treating the `0x5E553C403E454D4183147D6E88805770` input as a **string**, instead of a binary value. We can match the expected result in C# by doing the same:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var b = new byte[] {94, 85, 60, 64, 62, 69, 77, 65, 131, 20, 125, 110, 136, 128, 87, 112};
    var c = "0x" + ByteArrayToString(b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    var result = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

// Adapted from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/3043
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in ba)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

See it here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/YSlLJJ

Note the original C# in your question is still encoding all of the correct data. You can base-64 decode the `XlU8QD5FTUGDFH1uiIBXcA==` string to get back your original byte array. Anything different you see is something trying to treat that array as a string directly. And this is with much less storage space, CPU, and memory use. If possible, I'd stick with that, or if you need to match it to another system, *fix* that system (because it really is a bug there).